# Info.plist may not contain the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, healthkit, application-loader

When I try to upload my iOS + apple watch app to iTunes using Application Loader, I get the error message

> ERROR ITMS-90595: "Unsupported Key. The Info.plist of bundle Watchless.app/Watch/WatchlessWatchApp.app/PlugIns/WatchlessWatchApp Extension.appex may not contain the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key."

Info.plist contains

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>healthkit</string>
</array>
```

which I think is absolutely necessary because both, watch app and iOS app depend heavily on HealthKit.

The entry is generated when I turn on the HealthKit capability of the watch extension target.

I am running out of ideas what to change.

Using XCode 7.2, Application Loader 3.4

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` are just your way of saying "I don't want to be installed on device without this functionality".

Removing this will not affect your Watch extension using `HealthKit`.

Just remove the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` from the `plist` in your extension and it should be fine.